# Keeping FIRST unique row of each block in a dataframe

Tags: datatable, duplicates

I have a large dataframe (27million rows and 18 columns). The dataframe contains many dublicated rows, which I can drop by using, for example, the distinct function from data.table. However, this gives me only the first unique row, whereas I want to have all unique rows. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df<-setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 10)), c("code", "var1", "var2", "var3"))
df$code<-c("101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110") 
df$var1<-c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3,3) 
df$var2<-c(1, 1,1, 2, 2, 1,1,2, 3,3 )
df$var3<-c(1, 1,1, 2, 2, 1,1,2, 3,3 )

df<-as.data.table(df)

df<-df %>% distinct(var1, var2, var3, .keep_all=T)

## which gives:
code var1 var2 var3
1:  101    1    1    1
2:  104    2    2    2
3:  109    3    3    3

## however, I want:
  code var1 var2 var3
1  101    1    1    1
2  104    2    2    2
3  106    1    1    1
4  108    2    2    2
5  109    3    3    3
```

A data.table solution would be great due to the size of the original dataframe.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you mean by "unique rows". What you show that you want isn't necessarily unique rows as there are multiple rows with 2,2,2 or 1,1,1. Are the duplicates always next to each other? And then what you are wanting is the first unique one of each block?

Comment: Yes, exactly, what I want is to get the first unique of each block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution using `data.table` but it may be less than optimal for your dataset given its size becuase it creates some extra columns.

Although in your example data var1, var2, and var3 were always the same, I'm going to assume here that they do not have to be.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo) # for rollapplyr function

df<-setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = 10)), c("code", "var1", "var2", "var3"))
df$code<-c("101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110") 
df$var1<-c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3,3) 
df$var2<-c(1, 1,1, 2, 2, 1,1,2, 3,3 )
df$var3<-c(1, 1,1, 2, 2, 1,1,2, 3,3 )

df <- as.data.table(df)
```

The first step is to create a variable that signifies if the variable in row `i` is different from that in row `i-1`. We do this for each of the three variables. This takes the `diff` function, which calculates the difference in a vector between `i` and `i-1` and applies it across each column.

```
df[,dif1 := abs(rollapplyr(var1, 2, function(x){diff(x,lag = 1)}, fill = 1)),]
df[,dif2 := abs(rollapplyr(var2, 2, function(x){diff(x,lag = 1)}, fill = 1)),]
df[,dif3 := abs(rollapplyr(var3, 2, function(x){diff(x,lag = 1)}, fill = 1)),]
```

If any of those variables has changed from row `i-1` then it is not a duplicate. Because we took the absolute value of the change spit out by the `diff` function, this means any value above zero signifies a change. We can take the sum of the change across three variables, and then filter to those rows whose change is above zero.

```
df[,drop := sum(dif1, dif2, dif3), by = code]
df[drop>0, .(code, var1, var2, var3),]

code var1 var2 var3
1:  101    1    1    1
2:  104    2    2    2
3:  106    1    1    1
4:  108    2    2    2
5:  109    3    3    3
```

Again, not sure how fast it will be. I ran this on 1e4 rows and it took 0.829 sec and again on 1e6 rows and it took 51.118 sec, so it seems to scale okay.

Comment: Thank you @m.evans! Your code works nicely and solved my issue. It took a while to run it on my large dataset, but after 15-20min I had the results :)